# Operators to measure difference in Python

Tags: python, operators

Is there an operator that will look at the difference between integers, rather than tell me if they're bigger or smaller?

For example, is there a way for Python to tell me if the difference between `a` and `b` is larger than a certain value, rather than calculating if `a` is larger than `b`, and / or `b` is larger than `a`?

So if I would compare 5 to 10 it would return 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use [`abs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) to get the absolute value of a subtraction:

```
if abs(a - b) > 5:
```

Demo:

```
>>> a, b = 10, 5
>>> abs(a - b)
5
>>> a, b = 5, 10
>>> abs(a - b)
5
```